# Как вывести данные в функцию из словаря и списка в Python

Tags: python, функции, список, словарь

Есть следующие данные:

```
documents = [{'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Василий Гупкин'},
{'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Геннадий Покемонов'},
{'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Аристарх Павлов'}]
```

и

```
directories = {
'1': ['2207876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': []
```

По условию задачи необходимо создать функцию l, которая выводит полную информацию по всем документам. Я сделала следующий код:

```
def all_l():   
    if command == 'l':
        for k in documents:
            print(' '.join(list(k.values())), "полка хранения:",list(directories.keys()))
```

По которой вывод:

```
passport 2207 876234 Василий Гупкин полка хранения: ['1', '2', '3']
invoice 11-2 Геннадий Покемонов полка хранения: ['1', '2', '3']
insurance 10006 Аристарх Павлов полка хранения: ['1', '2', '3']
```

Нужен вывод по условию задачи, чтобы выводилась конкретная полка, на которой хранится документ:

```
2207 876234, тип: passport, владелец: Василий Гупкин, полка хранения: 1
11-2, тип: invoice, владелец: Геннадий Покемонов, полка хранения: 1
10006, тип: insurance, владелец: Аристарх Павлов, полка хранения: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берите `k['number']` и ищите в значениях словаря `directories` где есть такой номер. Найдёте - ключ словаря, соответствующий этому найденному значению и есть искомая полка. Полный код не пишу, всё-таки это учебное задание.

Дальше там можно оптимизировать (например, составить обратный словарь номер->полка, чтобы не искать в значениях, а получать номер полки моментально по ключу).

Comment: Разве в Питоне нет готовых классов, которые предоставляют hash and revhash одновременно?

Comment: @0andriy А где вы такое вообще видели, в каком языке? Я что-то первый раз про такое слышу. А было бы, наверное, полезно.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо) Запоздало конечно, но спасибо за ответ)